Flink Checkpoints Stalling and Timing Out with Latency-related Errors
Recently, I've upgraded an existing Flink job (previously running Flink 1.15) to run against the official Flink Kubernetes Operator (targeting Flink 1.18) and have started to see some strange behaviors surrounding checkpointing that haven't previously been seen in other jobs (or the job prior to the migration).
A bit of additional information about the job and deployment (only including potentially relevant bits):
spec:
  flinkConfiguration:
    # Checkpointing Configuration
    execution.checkpointing.interval: 10s
    execution.checkpointing.mode: EXACTLY_ONCE
    execution.checkpointing.tolerable-failed-checkpoints: "5"
    execution.checkpointing.unaligned: "true"
    ...
    # High Availability
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    high-availability.storageDir: gs://.../my-job/ha
    # Autoscaling (with in-place upgrades and default autoscaling configuration)
    job.scheduler: adaptive
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.enabled: "true"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.catch-up.duration: 5m
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.metrics.window: 3m
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.restart.time: 2m
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.stabilization.interval: 1m
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.target.utilization: "0.6"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.target.utilization.boundary: "0.2"
    kubernetes.operator.job.autoscaler.vertex.max-parallelism: "8"
    ...
    # Checkpointing / Savepointing Configuration
    state.checkpoints.dir: gs://.../my-job/checkpoints
    state.savepoints.dir: gs://.../my-job/savepoints
  podTemplate:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      # Configuration for writing to GCS for Checkpoints/Savepoints/HA
      - env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /flink/gcs-creds/key.json
        - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
          value: flink-gs-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar

What I'm experiencing is after the job starts running, it attempts a checkpoint and subequently stalls until the point of timing out. The job is configured to checkpoint every 10 seconds, however it will not move on or attempt the next checkpoint until the previous has fully-timed out (10 minutes) similar to the Checkpointing History shown below:

When reviewing over the Task Manager logs, I see quite a few latency warnings that I haven't previously seen before which I suspect are related to the checkpointing issues:
Apr 15, 2024 3:44:20 PM com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GhfsStorageStatistics updateMinMaxStats
INFO: Detected potential high latency for operation op_create. latencyMs=695; previousMaxLatencyMs=0; operationCount=3; context=gs://.../my-job/checkpoints/93adc4ebde39a17486133f0
...
Apr 15, 2024 4:04:19 PM com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GhfsStorageStatistics updateMinMaxStats
INFO: Detected potential high latency for operation stream_write_close_operations. 
latencyMs=247; previousMaxLatencyMs=246; operationCount=7; context=gs://...my-job/checkpoints/9
...
Apr 15, 2024 4:04:20 PM com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem repairImplicitDirectory
INFO: Successfully repaired 'gs://.../my-job/checkpoints/93adc4ebde39a17486133f0c3ef3f508/chk-3855/' directory.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the 1.18 Hadoop plug-in or something related to the configuration for the job itself, but it's continually failing and I'm not sure how to pinpoint the exact cause.

After some significant digging and tweaking with the job, I was finally able to get it to run as expected. It seems that the issue is related to the use of unaligned checkpoints as disabling the following configuration made an immediate impact to the job:
execution.checkpointing.unaligned: "false"

The issue itself appears to be a regression that was introduced in the Flink 1.18 release as I have several other jobs running that leverage unaligned checkpoints but target an earlier version of Flink (1.17.x). I haven't had any luck pinpointing the issue to a specific known issue in the Apache JIRA, but would love if someone more familiar with the issue could elaborate.

I'm currently facing the same issue and I use unalignedCheckpoints as well. I'll try to disable it and see how it goes.
Nonetheless, I created this issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-35388) on Flink JIRA.
